# How to determine version of iTextSharp?

Tags: visual-studio, itext

I'm using VS2022, and I received an old project, where iTextSharp was used, but I can't determine a specific version of the mentioned.

I've tried - Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for Solution...

But was unable to find iTextSharp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the assembly being included in source control and being referenced directly?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, we've got using iTextSharp.text.pdf, and
using iTextSharp.text included in our class.

Comment: And the solution builds successfully

Comment: Yeah, everything works fine

Comment: I'd check the project's references and check where iTextSharp is being included from. You should be able to locate the assembly. There may be some clues in the file or path name. If not you will have to check the assembly's version.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get by finding a dll, and checking the version. Nice little tip.
You could post those steps in an answer, so I can mark it as solved if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the assembly has been included directly in the source control, as was common place before nuget. Take a look in your project's references and you should be able to locate the dll. Checking the file's properties in VS should show you the assembly's details in the properties panel and should also show you which version is being used, if not the path or filename may give you a clue as to the version being used.